# Display multiple routes in mapbox

Tags: mapbox-android

I am trying to display multiple routes in mapbox,I also enabled alternative to true still multiple routes are not displayed,would like to plot multiple routes on a map. However, this is not working.Is there any ways to display multiple routes in mapbox?
I also attached my code below.

```
private void getRoute(MapboxMap mapboxMap, Point origin, Point destination) {
        client = MapboxDirections.builder()
                .origin(origin)
                .destination(destination)
                .overview(DirectionsCriteria.OVERVIEW_FULL)
                .profile(DirectionsCriteria.PROFILE_DRIVING)
                .accessToken(getString(R.string.mapbox_access_token))
                .alternatives(true)
                .build();

        client.enqueueCall(new Callback<DirectionsResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<DirectionsResponse> call, Response<DirectionsResponse> response) {
// You can get the generic HTTP info about the response
                Timber.d("Response code: " + response.code());
                if (response.body() == null) {
                    Timber.e("No routes found, make sure you set the right user and access token.");
                    return;
                } else if (response.body().routes().size() < 1) {
                    Timber.e("No routes found");
                    return;
                }

// Get the directions route
                currentRoute = response.body().routes().get(0);

// Make a toast which displays the route's distance
                Toast.makeText(DirectionsActivity.this, String.format(
                        "directions_activity_toast_message"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                if (mapboxMap != null) {
                    mapboxMap.getStyle(new Style.OnStyleLoaded() {
                        @Override
                        public void onStyleLoaded(@NonNull Style style) {

// Retrieve and update the source designated for showing the directions route
                            GeoJsonSource source = style.getSourceAs(ROUTE_SOURCE_ID);

// Create a LineString with the directions route's geometry and
// reset the GeoJSON source for the route LineLayer source
                            if (source != null) {
                                source.setGeoJson(LineString.fromPolyline(currentRoute.geometry(), PRECISION_6));
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
```